# Problem of Q() for and two condition in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose that I have these models:

```
class X(models.Model):
    interface = models.OneToOneField('Interface', related_name='x')

class Y(models.Model):
    interface = models.OneToOneField('Interface', related_name='y')
    
    
class Interface(models.Model):
    CHOICE = (
        (0, 'this is x'),
        (1, 'this is y'),
    )

    owner_type = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICE,)
```

Now, I want to get count  `Interface Objects` that dosen't have x relation and y relation. I used these two way:

```
z =  Interface.objects.filter(x__isnull=True).filter(y__isnull=True).count()
# Get correct number of objects 
x =  Interface.objects.filter(Q(x__isnull=True)and Q(y__isnull=True)).count()
# Get wrong number of objects
```

**The `z` return correct result but `x` return wrong number. Why this happend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python the `and` operator is not the same as the `&` (ampersand). `and` is the logical AND operator, whereas `&` is a bitwise operator. Hence when you would write `Q(x__isnull=True) and Q(y__isnull=True)` it will give you either *first* falsey value (if any are falsey) or the *last* truthy value. Hence in your case it gives `Q(y__isnull=True)`. Instead you want to use `&`:

```
x =  Interface.objects.filter(Q(x__isnull=True) & Q(y__isnull=True)).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `&` instead of `and`.

Or you can do it like this:

```
y =  Interface.objects.filter(x__isnull=True, y__isnull=True).count()
```